# Arab and Asian computers use more memory because of the characters used?

Tags: unicode, encoding, ascii

If the Arab and Asian characters used in the Unicode standard use more than 1 byte, that means computers Arabs and Asians spend more memory because of the characters used?

Comment: I'm pretty sure computers do not have a nationality. Strings encoded in UTF-8 takes more space when encoding text in Arabic. (In local codepages they take exactly 1 byte). Japanese, and other eastern languages are always multiple bytes per character

Comment: Yes. What will you do with the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about Arabic, so this answer focuses on Chinese only.

Technically, if you are using a representation like UTF-8, more bytes are required to represent a Chinese character (3 or 4 bytes, depending on whether the character is in BMP) than for an ASCII character (1 byte). However, a single Chinese character often expresses what a whole word in English does. So in the end, your text can end up shorter, even when using UTF-8 encoding.

When using other encodings, the space advantages of ASCII characters are even less. In UTF-16, each ASCII character takes 2 bytes, and a Chinese character takes 2 or 4 bytes (depending on whether it's in BMP). So if most of your Chinese text is in BMP, it has even more space advantage over English. :-) And of course, in UTF-32, every character takes 4 bytes, BMP or no.

Note that, no matter what encoding is used for persistent storage, many programming languages will use UTF-32 across the board, especially if random access to characters within a string is desired. That means ASCII characters confer no space advantages whatsoever within the process memory for those programming languages.

Comment: Arabic/Hebrew will take 2 bytes per character using UTF-8 but there are  local codepages with a single byte per character. ISO 8859-8 for hebrew ISO 8859-6 for Arabic

Comment: @odedsh Right, a good choice of encoding is one way to reduce the storage requirement for Arabic text (and pretty much any non-CJK language).